# Does MLE exist for an uniform distribution on an open interval?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, data-analysis

I am wondering if the Maximum Likelihood Estimate exists for a uniform distribution on $[0, \theta)$ (open interval on $\theta$). Choosing $\theta_{MLE}$ as $max\{\bar x\}$ would mean that the $\Pr(\bar x|\theta_{MLE}) = 0$, which obviously isn't the maximum of $\Pr(\bar{x})$.

I found many websites loosely interchanging the open and closed interval during the solution itself so I am not sure if people tend to give any attention to this.

Comment: Recall that for a continuous random variable $X$, $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ so whether the endpoints of the interval are included or not is irrelevant.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/391612/119261. For all practical purposes it is indeed irrelevant if we include the endpoints of the interval or not, though strictly mathematically MLE does not exist if you use the $(0,\theta)$ version.